# jQuery won't append append option tags inside of select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following for my JS code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newOptions = "{'East': 'first','West': 'second', 'North': 'third'}";
    var option = $('#type_form');

    option.empty(); 

    $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
        option.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(key));
    });
});
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<select id="type_form">
    <option value="first">First</option> 
    <option value="second">Second</option> 
</select>
```

The JS console in chrome doesn't throw me any error. All of the option tags are removed, but they're not replaced with anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that you can do : `$('<option />', {value: value, text: key});`

Comment: Hey, newOptions you have given is string it should be object so remove quotes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newOptions` should be an object not a string,

If you have it as a string then parse it to an object using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) - for browsers like IE8 which does not have native JSON support you have to add a library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newOptions = {"East": "first","West": "second", "North": "third"};
    var option = $('#type_form');

    option.empty(); 

    $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
        option.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(key));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must parse your JSON string :

```
$.each(JSON.parse(newOptions), function(key, value) {
```

EDIT : My answer supposes that your string comes from elsewhere. If it's really a literal, it's better to write it as a literal object directly, as shown by Arun.